# Solving $ \vert x+2 \rvert \le 6 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am having a hard time finding the answer for $$ \vert x+2 \rvert \le 6 $$
The answer has to be interval notation and the book says $$ 4 \le x \le 8 $$

There are examples in the book, and I found a rule on Khan Academy to solve absolute value inequalities.  The rule is $$ \lvert f(x) \rvert \lt a $$ $$-a \lt f(x) \lt a $$ If I follow it this is how I solve the problem.

The original equation is $ \lvert x+2 \rvert \le 6$

Then I start to solve...
$-6 \le x+2 $  and $6 \ge x+2$

The next step for me is
$ -8 \le x \le 4 $

This is where I am stuck.  I can not find away to find the book's answer.  It must be a reflection about the y axis that I am missing?  Why is it 8 and not -8?

Comment: Your answer is correct. The book is incorrect.

Comment: $|x-(-2)|\le6$ means that $x$ is within a distance of 6 from the point $-2$, so $-8\le x \le 4$

Comment: Also you can do a reality check such as: check that $x=0$ satisfies the original inequality, and also satisfies your solution, but does not satisfy the book's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you found on your own is correct. The book is wrong in this case; must be a printing error. The way you solved it is one of the correct ways to solve it analytically.

Comment: I don't think it's a printing error... They also swapped the 4 and the 8 :)

Comment: I give credit to the senior contributing author, Jay Abramson, and the other contributing authors of the book, They have taught me much!  The book is called PreCalculous and the publisher, I think, is Rice University, OpenStacks, original press 2014. I have the book on my Kindle.  To think of it as an oversight is strange. I am really trying to write down everything I have learned about functions and also document my favorite functions I found in this book.  I will have to include this analysis of an inequality absolute value function in my discussion and use this thread to confirm proof!